# Pyspark: Extract date from Datetime value

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I am trying to figure out, how to extract a date from a datetime value using Pyspark sql.

The datetime values look like this:

```
DateTime
2018-05-21T00:00:00.000-04:00
2016-02-22T02:00:02.234-06:00
```

When I now load this into a spark dataframe and try to extract the date (via

```
Date() or
Timestamp() and then Date()
```

I always get the error, that a date or timestamp value is expected, but a DateTime value was provided.

Can someone help me with retrieving the date from this value? I think, you need to provide a timezone for that - but since I already had problems extracting only the date, I first wanted to solve this.

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with the full error traceback? Please see [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Answer (score 41):

Pyspark has a `to_date` function to extract the date from a timestamp.  In your example you could create a new column with just the date by doing the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date

df = df.withColumn('date_only', to_date(col('date_time')))
```

If the column you are trying to convert is a string you can set the `format` parameter of `to_date` specifying the datetime format of the string.

You can read more about `to_date` in the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date).

Comment: what is func in your code?

Comment: @user15649753 - from pyspark.sql import functions as func

Answer (score 24):

You can use either
[date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format)
(or) [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) (or) [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) functions to extract date from the input string.

***Example:***

Input data df data as follows..

```
#sample dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([('2018-05-21T00:00:00.000-04:00',),('2016-02-22T02:00:02.234-06:00',)],['ts'])

#set UTC timestamp
spark.sql("set spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC")

df.show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------+
#|ts                           |
#+-----------------------------+
#|2018-05-21T00:00:00.000-04:00|
#|2016-02-22T02:00:02.234-06:00|
#+-----------------------------+
```

***1. Using `date_format()` function:***

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(date_format(col('ts'),"yyyy-MM-dd").alias('ts').cast("date")).show(10,False)
#+----------+
#|ts        |
#+----------+
#|2018-05-21|
#|2016-02-22|
#+----------+
```

***2. Using `to_date()` function:***

```
df.select(to_date(col('ts')).alias('ts').cast("date")).show(10,False)
#+----------+
#|ts        |
#+----------+
#|2018-05-21|
#|2016-02-22|
#+----------+
```

***3. Using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` functions:***

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('ts'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),"yyyy-MM-dd").alias("ts").cast("date")).show(10,False)
#+----------+
#|ts        |
#+----------+
#|2018-05-21|
#|2016-02-22|
#+----------+
```